# Expo-Router Bottom tabs with nested Stack Screen

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I am trying the new Expo-Router with a complex nesting navigation, currently i'm trying to display a screen with a presentation of modal, which itself is a part of a bottom tab navigation, but it is not presenting as a modal but as a simple stack screen:

Project layout:

```
app/
  _layout.tsx
  index.tsx
  (main)/
    _layout.tsx
    (tabs)/
      _layout.tsx
      home/
      create/
      profile/
      search/
      notifications/
```

(main)/(tabs)/_layout.tsx:

```
import {Tabs} from "expo-router/tabs";
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <Tabs.Screen name='home'/>
      <Tabs.Screen name='search'/>
      <Tabs.Screen name='create'/> // should be presented as modal
      <Tabs.Screen name='notifications'/>
      <Tabs.Screen name='profile'/>
    </Tabs>
  )
}
```

(main)/(tabs)/create/_layout.tsx

```
import {Stack} from "expo-router/stack";
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{presentation: "modal"}}/>
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

The `create` page should be a stack with presentation set to modal in order for it to work/render as a modal screen right?

Reproducible repo:- https://github.com/theartificialguy/Threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it using the `listener` prop in `Tabs.Screen`.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68900301/11685381

Answer (score 0):

#### solution

You can do this systematically by using the `navigation.getState()` method

Here's an example of using it to hide the bottom bar anytime the active screen has nested navigation

```js
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => {
        const state = navigation.getState();
        const hasNestedNavigation = state.routes[state.index].state?.index > 0; //  if the current state's route has a state, and its not the index of that route, then we've detected nested navigation
navigation
        return {
          tabBarStyle: {
            display: hasNestedNavigation ? 'none' : undefined, // hide for all nested navigation screens
          },
        };
      }}
    >
       {/** ... */}
    </Tabs>
```

This answer builds on the following resources:

- the [old way of achieving the same effect](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7464#issuecomment-445213997) in react navigation
- the [new way of accessing navigation state](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#dropped-dangerously-from-dangerouslygetparent-and-dangerouslygetstate) in react navigation

You can extend this answer to customize when you do or do not want the bottom bar to display without limit given the `navigation state`, so any usecase you have should be covered.

#### ⚠️ reminder

`initialRouteName` is required on each stack with `expo-router`

Otherwise, not only will this solution be broken on refreshes, but more importantly, for all situations with `expo-router` deeplinks and refreshes will not display the back button on your stack screens.

For example

```js
export const unstable_settings = {
  initialRouteName: '/index',
};
```

ref: https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/router-settings/

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to change the `href` of the create tab-button to point to the url of the create page:

```js
<Tabs.Screen name='create' options={{ href: "create" }} />
```