# An issue about nested navigator in Expo Router

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I am encountering an issue related to navigating in Expo Router.

[image of my project's navigator hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiHte.png)

As shown in the screenshot above, I have configured my router in the following way. I defined the *Stack Navigator* in `app/_layout.tsx`, the *Tabs Navigator* in `app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx`, and a separate *Stack Navigator* in each tab (home/profile) to display multiple screens within the same tab.

**Here's where the problem occurred:**

(`router` is returned object from useRouter hook)

1. Executed `router.push` from the `/` router to the `/home` router.
2. Executed `router.push` from the `/home` router to the `/welcome` router.
3. In order to return to the home tab, executed `router.push` to the `/home` router.

Upon executing the third step, instead of going to `/home`, it navigated back to `/`.

Through various tests, I found out that the problem is caused by the *Stack Navigator* nested inside the *Tabs Navigator*. When I removed the `_layout.tsx` files from `(tabs)/home` and `(tabs)/profile`, the problem disappeared.

However, I need to define the *Stack Navigator* in the `(tabs)/home,profile/_layout.tsx` file as I need to display multiple screens in each tab.

What can I do to make this work as intended?

I'm dying to solve this problem. I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expo-Router Bottom tabs with nested Stack Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658982/expo-router-bottom-tabs-with-nested-stack-screen)

Comment: You can do this with `navigation.getState()` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251731/3068233

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. My initial structure had the initial route at `index.tsx` but I wanted to nest a stack navigator inside it, so I changed the layout to`/index/...`. This resulted in similar navigation issues to what you describe.

I solved it by using `useNavigation` from `expo-router`, and following the [documentation from React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator) on navigating to a screen in a nested navigator. Gaining visibility into the names and paths of the routes by logging the navigation state also helped to navigate to the correct route names.

```
import { useNavigation } from 'expo-router';

...

const navigation = useNavigation()

...
console.log(JSON.stringify(navigation.getState()))

navigation.navigate("index", { screen: "index" })
```

[image: my projects tab navigator heirarchy]

Comment: Hi! I have the exact same problem you have. I want my the default view on a tabs layout to be a stack layout, which would require me to have my index file actually be an index folder. This is making expo-router go mad. I don't really understand your solution though, you are showing how to actively navigate somewhere, but I just want my default tab to be the correct one, but everything I try causes expo-router to error out. How did you go about doing this?