# Unable to Navigate Between Nested Stacks Inside Tab Navigator in Expo Router

Tags: expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I am currently facing an issue with navigating between nested stacks inside a tab navigator in my Expo project. I am using the Link component to navigate to the "account" tab on the first press, which works correctly. However, on subsequent presses, the navigation remains on the "search" tab instead of navigating back to the "account" tab.

[I've linked a screen recording here](https://imgur.com/a/xbRsWnd)

Link I am using for the navigation:

```
    <Link
      href={{
        pathname: `/(tabs)/account`,
      }}>
      <Text>
        Refine search settings
      </Text>
    </Link>
```

My navigation structure:

[image]

The expected behavior is that each press of the link should navigate to the "account" tab. However, it seems that the navigation is not being reset, and subsequent presses of the link result in staying on the "search" tab.

I have set up my navigation using a tab navigator with nested stacks.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to properly navigate between nested stacks inside a tab navigator in Expo would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Follow up - seems this is a solution, but not sure whether its the correct solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76802049/an-issue-about-nested-navigator-in-expo-router/76882109#76882109