# How to have a full screen nested route inside tabs layout of expo router

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, expo-router

I am using the tabs layout of Expo Router , and inside one tab, I have a nested stack layout. What I want to achieve is that when I press a button from the index page of the nested route to redirect to a new route, it should take up the entire screen, overlaying the tab icons at the bottom.

```js
// app/(tabs)/review/_layout.tsx
const ReviewLayout =()=>{

return <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="write_review"
        options={{ headerShown: false, presentation: "fullScreenModal" }} 
      /> 
    </Stack>
}
```

```js
// app/(tabs)/review/index.tsx
const Review =()=>{
const router = useRouter()
return <View><Button title="Write a Review" onPress={()=>router.push("/(tabs)/review/write_review.text")} /></View>
 }
```

I used the "fullScreenModal" property of the presentation props to the stack screen of 'write_review' but it still behind the tab bars (I am developing an android only app so I am not certain if this solution works on ios or not)

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/

Comment: It messes up the entire folder structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expo-Router Bottom tabs with nested Stack Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658982/expo-router-bottom-tabs-with-nested-stack-screen)

Comment: You can do this with `navigation.getState()` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251731/3068233